# BluetoothGatt.disconnect() turns on NFC

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, nfc

I have an app that connects to Bluetooth device, it's based on this example:

https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/src/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt/BluetoothLeService.html

Every time I call BluetoothGatt.disconnect() it enables NFC. I don't use NFC in the code, there is no NFC in the manifest.

Looks like BluetoothGatt.disconnect forces NfcService to start, it doesn't make any sense, it happens every time:

com.ble.ble I/BluetoothLeService: Disconnected from GATT server.
D/BtGatt.btif: btif_gattc_upstreams_evt: Event 14
D/IOP_DB_BT: db_query_create: id DisablePwlCtrReq :: key KEY_BDADDR, value 30:ae:a4:0d:79:e6
D/IOP_DB_BT: db_query_add_key: key KEY_LMP_MFCT, value 0
D/IOP_DB_BT: db_query_add_key: key KEY_LMP_VER, value 0:0
D/IOP_DB_BT: db_query_add_key: key KEY_DIR_ALL, value *
D/IOP_DB_BT: db_query_execute: result 1
D/BluetoothRemoteDevices: aclStateChangeCallback: State:DisConnected to Device:30:AE:A4:0D:79:E6
D/KeyguardViewMediator: Received android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED connectedBTforSmartLock = false
I/NfcService: android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED, restart
D/BleAutoConnectService: android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED
D/BleAutoConnectService: ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED, reason is 22linktype is 2
D/BleAutoConnectService: getAddress() - address ==> null
D/BluetoothAdapterService(1113351520): Get Bonded Devices being called
D/BluetoothAdapterService(1113351520): Get Bonded Devices being called
D/BluetoothAdapterService(1113351520): Get Bonded Devices being called
I/NfcService: Enabling NFC

Why it happens? Why NFC? How to prevent NFC from starting?

Tested on Samsung I9300, Android 4.3.